# Lift worker RAM memory limit

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to adjust a build job within jenkins, the problem is, it keeps failing due to lack of memory, I've adjusted java xmx but it did not solve the problem.

Turns out, I have RAM memory limit within the worker, I tried running those commands as part of the build script : "free -m" and "cat /proc/meminfo" and they both confirmed that job is being run with 1GB RAM limit, the server has more but the build isn't using it and it keeps failing due to lack of memory.

Please help me fix this, how can I lift that limit ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Heap or Permgen?
There are two OutOfMemoryErrors which people usually encounter. The first is related to heap space: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Heap space When you see this, you need to increase the maximum heap space. You can do this by adding the following to your JVM arguments -Xmx200m where you replace the number 200 with the new heap size in megabytes.

The second is related to PermGen: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space. When you see this, you need to increase the maximum Permanent Generation space, which is used for things like class files and interned strings. You can do this by adding the following to your JVM arguments -XX:MaxPermSize=128m where you replace the number 128 with the new PermGen size in megabytes.

Also note:
Memory Requirements for the Master
The amount of memory Jenkins needs is largely dependent on many factors, which is why the RAM allotted for it can range from 200 MB for a small installation to 70+ GB for a single and massive Jenkins master. However, you should be able to estimate the RAM required based on your project build needs.

Each build node connection will take 2-3 threads, which equals about 2 MB or more of memory. You will also need to factor in CPU overhead for Jenkins if there are a lot of users who will be accessing the Jenkins user interface.

It is generally a bad practice to allocate executors on a master, as builds can quickly overload a master’s CPU/memory/etc and crash the instance, causing unnecessary downtime. Instead, it is advisable to set up agents that the Jenkins master can delegate jobs to, keeping the bulk of the work off of the master itself.

Finally, there is a monitoring plugin from Jenkins that you can use:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Monitoring

Sources:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Monitoring
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Builds+failing+with+OutOfMemoryErrors
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/hardware-recommendations/#:~:text=The%20amount%20of%20memory%20Jenkins,single%20and%20massive%20Jenkins%20master.

Comment: I've added this line to /etc/defaults/jenkins :
JAVA_ARGS="-Xmx8000m -XX:MaxPermSize=3300m -Xms3000m -Xss100m -XX:DefaultMaxRAMFraction=1"
and it did not help